# Can Kinect for Windows work on an Xbox 360?

Tags: xbox-360, kinect

I realized that this is not a less popular concern (and more popular one being the reverse) so I want to post it here. I have a Kinect for Windows but I don't have an Xbox 360 to test this, so can it work on an Xbox 360?

Comment: There's a somewhat related question here, which may make me just use the 360 Kinect: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9804209/will-a-c-sharp-library-for-the-xbox-kinect-work-for-the-windows-kinect-sdk

Answer (score 3):

I own an Xbox 360 Slim bundled with Kinect for Xbox, and a Kinect for Windows. I tried plugging in the Kinect for Windows into the Xbox, and the console did NOT recognise it. So I can confirm that the Kinect for Windows will not work on the Xbox. On the other hand, the Kinext for Xbox -using the power adapter- does work on the PC.

Comment: There was never a question that the XBOX for Windows would NOT work on an XBOX 360.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/kinectforwindows/news/faq.aspx)...

> The Kinect for Windows sensor is a fully-tested and supported Kinect experience on Windows with features such as “near mode,” skeletal tracking control, API improvements, improved USB support across a range of Windows computers and Windows-specific 10’ acoustic models.
>
> The sensor was specifically designed to be used with PCs, with a shortened USB cable to ensure reliability across a broad range of computers, and the inclusion of a small dongle to improve coexistence with other USB peripherals.
>
> Kinect for Xbox 360, on the other hand, was built for and tested with the Xbox 360 only, not with any other platform, which is why it is not licensed for general commercial use, supported, or under warranty when used on any other platform.
>
> Finally, Microsoft has dedicated a large team of engineers to continual improvements of hardware and software associated with Kinect for Windows, and is committed to providing ongoing access to Microsoft's deep investment in human tracking and speech recognition.

Comment: Thanks. maybe i will just borrow some else's xbox and give it a try.

Comment: @Falcon - You can burrow one but it is unlikely the Xbox will even be recognise the device considering the Kinect for XBOX 360 ( current models ) actually uses a special USB interface. There is an adapator cord that allows XBOX 360 models without this dedecated port to accept a Kintect. It is for this reason the Kintect for Windows will NOT function with the XBOX 360.  The entire reason they released a different model is so they could improve upon it.  They cannot do this on the XBOX 360 model since they are limited to the performance of the LCD ( i.e. USB 2.0 ).

Comment: @Falcon If Microsoft, the company who makes them says that the Kinect sensor for Windows is different from the Kinect sensor for the XBox 360, and you decide you are going to try an XBox 360 version on a computer **anyway**... why did you ask the question, if you were going to ignore the answers?  I mean, were you just looking for validation of your own opinion, and regardless of the facts, you are just going to plug one in?  Again... if this was your intention, why ask in the first place?

Comment: @BonGart, as far as i know Kinect for XBox _works_ on PC. I appreciate your "answer" but it is _suggestive_, not _conclusive_. Maybe the question got migrated to a wrong place but I was hoping to find a **fact** and I honestly do not expect every possible question to have an immediate answer (and I hope you will agree so).

Comment: @Ramhound, Kinect for Windows uses a splitter to allow for extra power supply from an (external) adapter as well.

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be a lot of information on this, but a news article on Softpedia suggests that it won't:

> "Potential customers shouldn’t expect to use this version of the
>   sensor on an Xbox 360 console, however, as the Kinect for Windows
>   works only on computers that are running the software development
>   kit."

Article: [Special Kinect for Windows Sensor Out on February 1, Costs $250 (€195)](http://news.softpedia.com/news/Special-Kinect-For-Windows-Sensor-Out-on-February-1-Costs-250-195-245418.shtml)

Comment: Thanks. it seems so but i will borrow my friend's xbox and give it a try.

Comment: @Falcon: Please update us with your own answer when you find out! :) I'm holding off on getting one until I find out the answer to this question.